# Activemq BrokerService Without Port Number

Tags: activemq-classic

Is it possible to use activemq brokerservice without port number. I am using activemq as embeded to write my app logs to DB. But I am in trouble with open ports while side by side deploying to the weblogic

Answer (score 0):

If you only need in VM client connections you can use ActiveMQ's [VM Transport](http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html) and not add any other network based transports.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Can we use KahaDB with VM protocol

Comment: Yes, your connection just operates over an in VM pipe, everything else on the Broker operates as normal.